# How to debug LPC1768 using Keil + H-JTAG over LPT

Tags: debugging, cortex-m, keil

I have a [LPC1768 based board](http://shop.ngxtechnologies.com/product_info.php?cPath=21&products_id=65&osCsid=5b6dfdb35d26d50d6ed577a68ba37998). And a [H-Jtag](http://shop.ngxtechnologies.com/product_info.php?cPath=26&products_id=29) Debugger(LPT based). I am able to Detect/Erase/Flash HEX files to the LPC1768 using H-JTAG [software](http://www.hjtag.com/).

I want to debug my board inside keil uVision. As I go into debug mode keil gives 'USB connection Error' and subsequently no code updation/debug happens. I think It shouldn't be looking for a usb connection, but it should be connecting to the H-Jtag server running in background which it doesn't.I couldn't find a setting which I can configure to tell keil to look/connect to H-JTAG server.

Anybody who has done this please point me in right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the debugging Working by following [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9hTyDpg4JfE).

Here is the list of steps for reference.

1. Install the latest [H-JTAG software](http://www.hjtag.com/upimg/H-JTAG%20V2.1%20RELEASE.rar) from [H-Jtag site](http://www.hjtag.com/en/).
2. Open **Toolconf.exe**(Part of H-Jtag software installation). And pass the **TOOLS.INI**(Located inside the directory where you installed uVision/Keil MDK. Mine is at "C:\Embedded\keil\")
3. Open **Flasher.exe**, Select proper **Target**(mine was NXP --> LPC1768) in **Flash Selection** menu, and in **Programming Menu** set the *TYPE* to **Auto Flash Download**
4. Open the **H-jtag.exe**. Go to the **Setting** tab **USB/LPT Selection** Option select **LPT** and set proper values in **LPT Jtag settings** and **LPT Port settings** options (usually default settings will work).
   Finally, go to **Flasher** tab and Check on the ***AUTO DOWNLOAD*** option. That's it !

Now you are ready to debug the device( LPC1768 ) inside uVision. Open the uVision and do select the **H-JTAG CORTEX M3** for **Debug** and **Utilities** TABs inside **Project Property** window.

Write, compile, Build and  Start Debugging !